# Запуск php парсера по расписанию через CURL

Tags: php, парсер, curl

**Здравствуйте, уважаемые товарищи программисты, прошу помочь оптимизировать скрипт, так как столкнулся с ошибкой 504 Gateway Timeout и похоже кроме оптимизации ему ничего не поможет, ниже подробнее.**

Сам парсер находится по пути **domen.com/import/import.php** (GET параметр **number** номер документа для обработки xml файлов (категории, атрибуты (import0.xml) и товары (от import1 и выше) )  полученных с 1С (import0-import5.xml), **key** - это секретный ключ, чтобы посторонние не запустили парсер

**domen.com/import/import.php?number=1&key=210236** пример запуска самого парсера напрямую

Вызов парсеров осуществляется через **curl по расписанию скриптом-планировщиком worker.php**  - запускает по CURL скрипты в зависимости от статуса обработан скрипт или нет (статус берется из базы), затем, после успешной обработки от парсера **worker.php** записывается в базу **status 1** чтоб повторно его не обрабатывать.

Самый интересный момент, если запустить отдельно парсер с браузера ВРУЧНУЮ domen.com/import/import.php?number=1&key=210236 , то все работать будет успешно, ответом будет "good", НО если тоже самое через curl в worker.php запустить то получаю ошибку **504 Gateway Timeout**, но при этом **worker.php** падает, но сам парсер (import.php), который вызвал curl, продолжает работать до последнего корректно (проверял).

То есть вывод: каким -то удивительным образом времени исполнения скрипта хватает на сам парсер (**import.php**), но не хватает на обработчик задач, запускающего его по CURL

**Делал:**
время исполнения скрипта увеличил сначала max_execution_time до 6000 , потом ставил 0 (бесконечно)
На всякий случай увеличил память до 1024 Мб

Ставил в скрипте:
set_time_limit(0)

ini_set('max_execution_time', -1); - в интернете видел подобное

**Ничего не помогает**

**Очень был бы признателен если бы смогли помочь каким-нибудь советом по оптимизации скрипта**

```
    <?
include 'db.php';
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//проверяем текущее время

 $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$time = strtotime($datetime);
$time = $time - (5 * 60);
$datecron = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

function go_parse($url){

$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36';

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 12000);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12000);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
return $query;

}


function parsing_file($namefile){

  global  $mysqli;
 global  $datetime;

$skey = '676236';    

$key = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $namefile);// узнаем номер импорт-файла (пример import1.xml значит ключ = 1)

echo 'key = '.$key.'<br>'; //для отладки

if ($key == '0'){
$status = go_parse("https://domen.com/import/groups.php?key=$skey"); //запускаем скрипт парсинга категорий и атрибутов
 echo $status = trim($status);
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "File import$key обработан"; //для отладки
$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('File import$key успешно обработан','1','$datetime');");           
      }else{
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('File import$key обработан c ошибкой','0','$datetime');");      

exit;
}



}else{


$parseUrl = "https://domen.com/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey"; //запуск скрипта парсинга товаров

    $status = go_parse($parseUrl);
 echo   $status = trim($status);
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "File import$key обработан";
$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('File import$key успешно обработан','1','$datetime');");           
      }else{
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('File import$key обработан c ошибкой','0','$datetime');");     
}    

}

}



$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * 
    FROM `cronjob` 
    WHERE 
        `date` <= '$datecron' 
         AND `status` = '0' 
    ORDER BY `jobfile` 
    LIMIT 1");


    $row = $result->fetch_object();
parsing_file(trim($row->jobfile));

echo 'parsing '.$row->jobfile.'<br>';
exit;



?>
```

Comment: когда совсем все непонятно используют логгирование. в узких местах скрипта пишут в логфайл инфу, потом смотрят где затык

Comment: у меня лог в базе, он читается в админпанели

Comment: Делал: время исполнения скрипта увеличил сначала max_execution_time до 6000 , потом ставил 0 (бесконечно) На всякий случай увеличил память до 1024 Мб

это вы где делали?

Comment: а cURL то в этой задаче вообще зачем?

Comment: просто так вышло что file_get_contents не работал как надо и выдавал ошибку, я думал через консоль через exec запускать но не знал как get параметры передавать + необхимо чтоб был ответ от парсера, чтобы записать статус в базу что обработалось

Comment: EatMyDust, memory_limit в php ini

Comment: я просто не понял смысла. у вас скрипты на разных серверах? Почему в крон нельзя добавить сам парсер, зачем его запускать через курл?

Comment: Все на одном сервере. Просто в разных скриптах. Вы имеете ввиду через include подгрузить скрипты? Но тогда как передать Get параметры чтобы скрипты работали? Ведь у них есть динамические переменные....хотя как вариант если если сделать функцией парсеры и потом их подгружать вписывая в тело функции динамическую переменную, хорошая идея?

Comment: напрямую в крон нельзя так как в Get парметре меняется обрабатываемый файл, в соответствии с задачей создаваемой при загрузке импорт-файлов (их кол-во может быть разным)

Comment: вообщем перевел все в функции и подгрузил из планировщика

Comment: я про то, что запускать скрипт через внешнее соединение с сервером это несколько странно. Мало того, что при отсутсвии сети у вас и работать ничего не будет,дак вы еще и загоняетесь в  рамки сетевого протокола и лимитов времени выполнения запроса.  
в запускающем же скрипте вы откуда то знаете какие параметры передать. Почему таким же образом не может это узнать скрипт обработчик?

Comment: дад Вы правы)  именн так и сделал) спасибо Вам